# React Reflux: Correct way to initiate stores and update dependent components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

I'm just starting with Reflux and React. I've watched several React/flux tutorials/videos, but I haven't found the correct way to set up my application with Reflux/React and React Router:

Imagine I have the following url: localhost:9000/projects/1/roles/2/action/3. Based on the url I should be able to trace back the state of the application. So in my Route handler I have the following set-up:

**App.cjsx**

```
routes = (
  <Route handler={AppWrapper}>
    <Route name="project" ...
    <Route name="action" handler={Action} path="/project/:project_id/roles/:role_id/actions/:action_id" />
  </Route>
)
```

In this case, {Action} is the component that should receive data from the store. This Action-component listens to the ActionStore to receive data:

```
componentWillMount: () ->
  actionStore.listen (actions) =>
    @setState({ actions: actions })
```

According to several tutorials, I should initiate my store in the bootstrap, so I added the following line in my App.cjsx:

```
ActionStore     = require('./stores/ActionStore.cjsx')
```

The actionstore has the following initiate method:

```
actionStore = Reflux.createStore 
    init: () ->
        $.ajax
          url: 'rest/mock' + period.name + '.json'
          dataType: 'json'
          success: (actions) =>
            @trigger(actions)
          error: (xhr, status, err) ->
            console.log('err:' + err)
        return  

module.exports = actionStore
```

My problem is that the flow in the application is not correct. The flow is now:

1. Create and initiate ActionStore
2. Store initiates and loads actions from server
3. Initiate Action component (add listener to store)

So the actionstore has already received the data, after that the component is initialized, so it never gets the trigger from the actionstore. How do I set this up with React Router and Reflux the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionStore could keep the `actions` data in a local `state` variable, and let components access it via `actionStore.getState()`.

Thus, in your components, you could simply do

```
getInitialState: () ->
  actionStore.getState()

componentWillMount: () ->
  actionStore.listen () =>
    @setState(actionStore.getState())
```

And your store would look like

```
actionStore = Reflux.createStore 
    init: () ->
        @state = {};

        $.ajax
          url: 'rest/mock' + period.name + '.json'
          dataType: 'json'
          success: (actions) =>
            @state = { actions }
            @trigger()
          error: (xhr, status, err) ->
            console.log('err:' + err)
        return

    getState: () ->
        @state

module.exports = actionStore
```

Comment: This works indeed, but how should I deal with the url params? Router.State.getParams() is not accessible in the store.

Comment: You can expose a method `getActions(params)` on the store which retrieves actions with ajax and calls `@trigger()` when the data is received and stored. Then, you just need to call that method in the `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method of your component.

You can use the [`Router.State` mixin](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/mixins/State.md) to retrieve the url params from within a component.

Comment: But what would you do in the case of multiple components listening to that store? Which one should do the call to the store to update based on the params?

Comment: I'd do the call in the route handler component.